# UITextView, Full Screen Mode and Exiting with UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I'm trying to make a button which Full Size the `UITextView` in my demo app. And resize it to its original size after I RE-touch the button again (AKA Exit Full Screen Mode).

I never tried to add more than one Action on 1 UIButton.

```
-(IBAction)clickButtonFullSize:(id)sender
{
        CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [myText setFrame:r];
}

-(IBAction)clickButtonReSize:(id)sender
{
    [myText setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
}
```

The first method is working fine when touching the `UIButton`. But how can I link the second method with the same button to reSize it (exit the full screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by managing `tag` of your button. No need for two `IBActions`.

```
-(IBAction)clickButtonFullSize:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;

    if (btn.tag == 0) 
    {
        btn.tag = 1;

        CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [myText setFrame:r];

    }
    else 
    {
        btn.tag = 0;

        [myText setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];

    }

}
```

Comment: And if you want to add two different IBActions then you need to assign for two different events but that will not a good idea!

Comment: Nice. Never came across to this method. Will try it after I finish my break.

Comment: Q! Does using 'tag' differ than using DJPlayer method?

Answer (score 1):

link both actions to the same UIButton and create a boolean in the first method.  Change the boolean at exit of the 1st function and throw an if in the 2nd method.

Comment: This is what I did at first. I wanted another better way though.

Comment: you can also do 1 IBAction that w/ an if statement the checks the framesize.  I personally wouldn't go flipping tag values for a button, but that's just my person opinion (I feel tags should be static).

Answer (score 0):

Use the same method for both resizes but check instead, if the button is full size then make it smaller and vice versa.

Either that or create a bool that holds the fact that the buttons full size and when the methods called it checks it.

You can point to two different methods on the same button.